# OpenCV Polylines excessive CPU usage

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv3.0

I am receiving a videostream (640x480p) via UDP and use OpenCV's imdecode() to decode every frame in the same thread. If correctly decoded the frame is passed to a newly started thread for image processing (findChessboardCorners() and polylines()) and the thread is detached.

The receiving and decoding part works perfectly but I logged the execution time for polylines() and it starts at about 5ms and gets worse the longer the program runs (up to 4000ms and more). Visual Studio's performance profiler reported, that polylines() uses ~98% of the CPU.  the vector with points to draw using polylines() consists of 40 points.

Even though i am detaching each thread, what could cause this performance loss? (even tested it with an Intel Xeon)

```
void decode(Mat videoFrame) {

Mat rotationMat;
Mat translationMat;
Mat chessboard;
resize(videoFrame, chessboard, Size(), resizeFactor, resizeFactor);
Size patternSize(chessboardSize.front(), chessboardSize.back());
vector<Point2f> corners;
vector<Point2f> imagePoints;
bool patternFound = findChessboardCorners(chessboard, patternSize, corners, CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH + CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK);

if (patternFound) {
    solvePnP(objectPoints, corners, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rotationMat, translationMat);
    vector<Point3d> path_3d = fahrspur.computePath(steeringAngle);
    vector<Point2d> path_2d;
    projectPoints(path_3d, rotationMat, translationMat, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, path_2d);

    Mat curve(path_2d, true);
    curve.convertTo(curve, CV_32S);
    double t4 = getCurrentTime();
    polylines(chessboard, curve, false, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 10, CV_AA);
    double t5 = getCurrentTime();
    cout << "time to execute polylines: " << t5-t4 << "ms" << endl;

    assignFrameVideo(chessboard);
}
```

A new thread with this decode method is started from another thread, used for receiving the frames, in a while loop:

```
Mat frameVideo;
while(1) {
    //code for receiving a single frame, decode it and store it in frameVideo.
    thread decodeThread = thread(decode, frameVideo);
    decodeThread.detach();
}
```

I also used the second option to use polylines() that way:

```
const Point *pts = (const Point*)Mat(path_2d).data;
int npts = Mat(path_2d).rows;
polylines(chessboard, &pts, &npts, 1, false, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 5);
```

But that does not work at all, the image is displayed without any lines.

Comment: This code can get badly out of hand when the processing time is longer than the frame decoding time.  After a while you can have *thousands* of threads running, possibly all competing over an internal lock that polylines() uses.  You must throttle with a semaphore, don't allow more threads than you have processor cores.  Verify this in VS with the Debug > Windows > Threads debugger window.

Comment: thank you for your answer.
I kept track of the total number of threads currently executing the decode function, and it did not exceed 3-5. Also the threads debugger window showed that there are never more than 20 threads running, which should be managable, right?

I tested it running the decode function in a single thread, instead of starting a new thread everytime, and even then the execution time for polylines() went continously up. Maybe rather my use of polylines() has flaws, than it is a multithreading issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved it by replacing CV_AA with LINE_4 as a parameter in polylines().
apparently the anti aliasing of the drawn line is the heavy part, now it runs within 0-1 ms.